# SQL Association Count Best Practice

Tags: sql, database, api, database-design, api-design

Imagine I have a Parent.hasMany(Child) relationship, if I have an API to query a Parent but also need to surface how many children this parent has, I have 2 immediate options:

1. Run a query on `COUNT(child.id)` (I feel this must be very hard to scale as we add more and more children in for a given `Parent`
2. Maybe have a `n_count` attribute defined on the Parent and do a SQL transaction to modify the count on the parent every time a `Child` is created/deleted

Which is the better option here, or is there a third and best way?

Comment: I don't get it. Are you looking for a number of distinct childs for each parent ?

Comment: @Houari im looking for the total number of children associated to a given parent

Answer (score 0):

Storing n_count in the parent is generally considered undesirable because it is redundant information (information which can be obtained more reliably by counting the child records). Having said that, if the updates to the parent and child rows (n_count) is controlled to **guarantee** correct updates (by database triggers, for example), then this can be called a type of 'controlled de-normalisation', and used for performance improvement (only improves read-queries, updates/inserts will be slower, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the response, is it recommended to scan the children table every time we run the query on a parent then? Im just concerned the performance impact might be significant when we get to something like a parent having 1000s of children

Comment: From a purist view: yes. Assuming that you have an index on the foreign key of the child table, and this index having just one integer column (parent_id), such queries can be satisfied by just reading the index structure and will be very quick even if it is thousands.